# Android - Best Way to do a button list to play different tracks

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I need to Make an activity of an app that is simply a list of about 30 buttons in the same Page, and when the user taps on one of them, the Phone have to play a Short audio track contained in raw folder.

What is the Best Way to organize data without repeating a Lot of Lines of code?

Thank you

Comment: Keywords: ListView, ArrayAdapter, Layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably would have gone with Spinners. They look organized and creates a list that will be helpful for you when making 30 buttons on the same page.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Hope this helps.